# Any info on this frame?

Tags: identify-this-bike, bmx

[image]

Grips say it’s a Mongoose.  Crank says Tourney Tuf-neck USA.  Only other markings I see are ‘112 83’ and ‘WALD 20’.  Found it in the rafters of the garage I just bought.  TIA!

Comment: Why do you want to know this?

Comment: Because I want to know if it’s worth trying to save, or if it belongs in the scrap pile?

Comment: Depends on how much you want to spend restoring it. I don't think there's any monetary value however

Answer (score 2):

Here are four things about your frame that make it distinctive.

1. The rear dropout is horizontal rather than the track type as most double diamond BMX bikes have
2. The seat stay bend connecting to the dropout.
   [image]
3. There seems to be a brace at the seat tube/top tube/seat stay junction. Not sure what that is but it is unusual.
   [image]
4. The gusset design, while similar to other BMX bikes it is unique in the details
   [image]

I've done some searching but have not found a match yet. One of the best references is [bmxmuseum.com](https://bmxmuseum.com/).
Maybe these observations will help you find a match.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chainring tuf necks cranks 3 piece sugino tourney ano blue big,  looks to have either redline or  race Inc v bars big and a cheap Troxell vintage seat. (Everything described except the seat are really expensive parts.) Frame throws me, it looks like parts could be copied from a old vintage mongoose looptail. Wheels look steel with coaster brake but look for stamp near valve stem hole. I actually have a good set of ukai steel wheels (FE) blue off s very early goose with a bendix coaster.

Comment: What's with the "$$$" and "$$$$;" are you trying to indicate "pricey" or "expensive?"  You could improve this post by writing more clearly.

Comment: Yes dollars signs means there worth good amount of money.chain ring depending on condition like all things between 40-$100 tourney crank set with bottom bracket once again depending on condition between 150-350 that includes the tapered spindel and full bottom bracket.now the bars hopefully they are vintage raceing Inc bars and they aren't hammedto.bad no big huge chunks missing once again condition is key to.the right person if there nice 300-400.if there beat 50 bucks. Sorry about the first response it was late I just got.out of hospital was jumped by 3 guys for walking on the wrong street

Comment: That's what the guy said to.me then all of a sudden my head was getting bashed in by bricks one guy was trying to pull my eyes of the socket with his thumbs buried on my eyes and wouldnt.let go next time.i woke up I was being life flight to.portland Oregon trama center I was awake for 2 seconds enough to see one house  out the side of the helicopter and I was out again 60 grand for a helicopter ride is what they are charging me 163 stitches to.my head and face and they amputated my right index finger so my vision is always double or triple so all this is most written by muscle memory sorry